# Get git top level directory in windows format CMD

Tags: git, sed, cmd

How can I set the output of this to a variable in CMD

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel |  sed -e s/\//\\/g
```

I tried:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('git rev-parse --show-toplevel |  sed -e s/\//\\/g ') 
do set "var=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the pipe ([in bat shell, escape is '`^`'](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('git rev-parse --show-toplevel ^|  sed -e s/\//\\/g ') do (
  set "var=%%A"
)
echo "A='%A%'"
```